# set variable after creating contextmenu

Tags: java, android, variables, contextmenu

I'm creating a soundboard.
When I click on a button, the soundfile is played and `selectedSoundId` is defined with `soundIds[i];`

If I long press the button, before button is "short" pressed, the `selectedSoundId` is not defined.
So I need to define it, even if I didn't "shortpress" the button.

I figured out I've to define it after "`onCreateContextMenu`", but how?

```
public class Activity2 extends TabActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    int selectedSoundId;
    int random = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);  

        //Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

        TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("text1").setContent(R.id.tab1));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("text2").setContent(R.id.tab2));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("text3").setContent(R.id.tab3));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setIndicator("text4").setContent(R.id.tab4));

        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

        final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        final Resources res = getResources();

        //just keep them in the same order,
        final int[] buttonIds = { R.id.button1, R.id.button2,};
        final int[] soundIds = { R.raw.sound1, R.raw.sound2, };

        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //find the index that matches the button's ID, and then reset
                //the MediaPlayer instance, set the data source to the corresponding
                //sound effect, prepare it, and start it playing.
                for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
                    if(v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) {
                        selectedSoundId = soundIds[i];
                        AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(soundIds[i]);
                        player.reset();
                        try {
                            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            player.prepare();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        player.start();

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
      //set the same listener for every button ID, no need
        //to keep a reference to every button
        for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
            Button soundButton = (Button)findViewById(buttonIds[i]);
            registerForContextMenu(soundButton);
            soundButton.setOnClickListener(listener);

        }



    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
     super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
     menu.setHeaderTitle("Save as...");
     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Ringtone");
     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Notification");

// How do I give SelectedsoundId here the value of soundIds[i]
 //Like : selectedSoundId = soundIds[i];

    }
```

**UPDATE**

I added this code in the `OnCreateContextMenu` and I think it's working correctly now.
I'm not sure if `v.getId();` is necessary?

```
 v.getId();
     for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
           if(v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) {
               selectedSoundId = soundIds[i];
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onCreateContextMenu()` method has a parameter named `View v` that represent the `View` for which the `ContextMenu` is being built. So from this you could get the ID (`v.getId()`) and then, like you did in the `View.OnClickListener listener`, find out the position in the `buttonIds` array and then set the `selectedSoundId` accordingly.

Also this:

```
menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Ringtone");
```

should be something like this:

```
menu.add(Menu.NONE, UNIQUE_ID, Menu.NONE, "Ringtone");
```

**Edit:**

In the code you added i see the line `v.getId();` before your for loop, that isn't necessary.
Regarding my menu edit you should assign a unique ID for your menu item so in the method `onContextItemSelected()` you can find out which menu item the user pick([see this class as an example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/LinearLayout8.html)). In the other fields you could use 0 or Menu.NONE.

Comment: I've updated the post with new additional code, see the edit.
What do you mean with the menu edit?